# What's a term that can encompass "check in" and "check out"?

Tags: word-choice

The "check in" and "check out" here is not of a hotel, but like of an hourly work freelance "check in" and "check out" type. So when the user "check in", they are considered show up to work. And when the user "check out", they are considered off from work. I need to make a menu in app that if the user selects it, will show another menu that says "check in" and "check out". But to call the menu "checks" feel a little bit off.

Comment: Does the follow-up menu have "timecard" functionality?  Or does it just have the two choices of "check in" and "check out"?

Comment: If your application stores enough state, it can figure out whether the user is currently checked in or not.  This would allow the first menu to have only the relevant choice (check in or check out), instead of forcing the user to click on two layers of menus.

Comment: You might get better answers on the [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Current Status"** could probably work, having states *checked in* and *checked out* inside that tab.

Comment: Oh, “set status” will probably be what I’m looking for. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a single term that means “**start *or* stop work**”.

In electronics, or logic, it it would be to **Toggle** operation, or power, or activity.  An “On/Off” button has the same effect and there isn’t really a more common name for that besides a **toggle**.

Since you’re designing software, this question crosses over into UX or Software Design stack exchanges, but you could use [**Start Work/Stop Work**] or [**Check In/Check Out**] or [**Check In/Out**].